# oAuth2 Token validation/verification in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Does Spring provide a pre-built way of token validation/verification if the authorization server and resource server reside on different boxes? Is there a best practice? What do you think about creating my own service at the authorization server that the resource server can call for validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that needed?   The Resource Server's OAuth2ProtectedResourceFilter should validate the token against the same database that the Authorization Server used to store the token.

Comment: Yeah we figured that one out but I was wondering if there's another db independent solution that comes out of the box. I couldn't find one but just wanted to make sure I didn't miss something. Thanks for the answer

Comment: No problem - no, nothing out of the box.

Comment: @sourcedelica - I am trying to implement OAuth2 on separate servers such Authorization server, resource server, client server all these servers are running on different ports. I am successfully getting the login form page but when submitting the credentials it is giving me 401 unauthorized error.
here is link for my oAuth2 implementation. any suggestions would be appreciated.
here is the link https://github.com/hatemjaber/oauth2-vanilla-custom

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using RemoteTokenService with ClientId, ClientSecret and check_token url on resource server. And It is working for me.
You just need to create a Bean on Resource server.